# how to call onOptionsItemSelected on a different activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methods

I have an activity with uses *onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)* method in FolderActivity and I want to call this method on another activity (MainActivity)
the main activity uses CMU Sphinx - Speech Recognition Toolkit. 
I need to call some methods from FolderActivity to MainActivity.

```
    package com.evolution.filemanager.folders;

    import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.ActionBar;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Fragment;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Gravity;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.WindowManager;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.evolution.filemanager.FileManagerApplication;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.about.AboutActivity;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.clipboard.Clipboard;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.clipboard.Clipboard.ClipboardListener;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.clipboard.ClipboardFileAdapter;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.favourites.FavouritesManager;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.favourites.FavouritesManager.FavouritesListener;
    import com.evolution.filemanager.nav_drawer.NavDrawerAdapter;
    import com.evolution.utils.FontApplicator;
    import com.evolution.utils.ListViewUtils;

    import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo.R;

    public class FolderActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener, ClipboardListener, FavouritesListener
    {   
        public static class FolderNotOpenException extends Exception
        {

        }

        private static final String LOG_TAG = "Main Activity";

        public static final String EXTRA_DIR = FolderFragment.EXTRA_DIR;

        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
        File lastFolder=null;
        private FontApplicator fontApplicator;

        public static Activity FOLDERACTIVITY;

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_folder);

            setupDrawers();
            Clipboard.getInstance().addListener(this);

            FOLDERACTIVITY = this;

            fontApplicator = new FontApplicator(getApplicationContext(), "Roboto_Light.ttf").applyFont(getWindow().getDecorView());
        }

        public FontApplicator getFontApplicator()
        {
            return fontApplicator;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy()
        {
            Clipboard.getInstance().removeListener(this);
            FileManagerApplication application = (FileManagerApplication) getApplication();
            application.getFavouritesManager().removeFavouritesListener(this);
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void setLastFolder(File lastFolder)
        {
            this.lastFolder = lastFolder;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPause()
        {
            if (lastFolder != null)
            {
                FileManagerApplication application = (FileManagerApplication) getApplication();
                application.getAppPreferences().setStartFolder(lastFolder).saveChanges(getApplicationContext());
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Saved last folder "+lastFolder.toString());
            }
            super.onPause();
        }

        public void setActionbarVisible(boolean visible)
        {
            ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
            if (actionBar == null) return;
            if (visible)
            {
                actionBar.show();
                setSystemBarTranslucency(false);
            }
            else
            {
                actionBar.hide();
                setSystemBarTranslucency(true);
            }
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        protected void setSystemBarTranslucency(boolean translucent)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) return;

            if (translucent)
            {
                getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            }
            else
            {
                WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
                params.flags &= (~WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
                getWindow().setAttributes(params);
                getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
            }
        }

        public void setupDrawers()
        {
            this.drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.open_drawer, R.string.close_drawer)
            {
                boolean actionBarShown = false;

                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
                {
                    makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawer open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    setActionbarVisible(true);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
                {
                    makeText(getApplicationContext(), "drawer close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    actionBarShown=false;
                    super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    invalidateOptionsMenu();
                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
                {
                    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
                    if (slideOffset > 0 && actionBarShown == false)
                    {
                        actionBarShown = true;
                        setActionbarVisible(true);
                    }
                    else if (slideOffset <= 0) actionBarShown = false;
                }
            };
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.START);
            drawerLayout.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    //      drawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, Gravity.END);

            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

            setupNavDrawer();
            setupClipboardDrawer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed()
        {
            if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            else if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END))
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
            else
                super.onBackPressed();
        }

        void setupNavDrawer()
        {
            FileManagerApplication application = (FileManagerApplication) getApplication();

            // add listview header to push items below the actionbar
            ListView navListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNavigation);
            ListViewUtils.addListViewPadding(navListView, this, true);

            loadFavourites(application.getFavouritesManager());
            application.getFavouritesManager().addFavouritesListener(this);
        }

        void setupClipboardDrawer()
        {
            // add listview header to push items below the actionbar
            ListView clipboardListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listClipboard);
            ListViewUtils.addListViewHeader(clipboardListView, this);
            onClipboardContentsChange(Clipboard.getInstance());
        }

        void loadFavourites(FavouritesManager favouritesManager)
        {
            ListView listNavigation = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listNavigation);
            NavDrawerAdapter navDrawerAdapter = new NavDrawerAdapter(this, new ArrayList<NavDrawerAdapter.NavDrawerItem>(favouritesManager.getFolders()));
            navDrawerAdapter.setFontApplicator(fontApplicator);
            listNavigation.setAdapter(navDrawerAdapter);
            listNavigation.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

            if (getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment) == null)
            {
                FolderFragment folderFragment = new FolderFragment();
                if (getIntent().hasExtra(EXTRA_DIR))
                {
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    args.putString(FolderFragment.EXTRA_DIR, getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_DIR));
                    folderFragment.setArguments(args);
                }

                getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment, folderFragment)
                    .commit();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            makeText(getApplicationContext(), "unsa ni?", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            actionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {

            makeText(getApplicationContext(), item.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
                return true;
            switch (item.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.menu_about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AboutActivity.class));
                    return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void showFragment(Fragment fragment)
        {
            getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.fragment, fragment)
                .commit();
        }

        public void goBack()
        {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        public FolderFragment getFolderFragment()
        {
            Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment);
            if (fragment instanceof FolderFragment)
                return (FolderFragment) fragment;
            else return null;

        }

        public File getCurrentFolder() throws FolderNotOpenException
        {
            FolderFragment folderFragment = getFolderFragment();
            if (folderFragment == null)
                throw new FolderNotOpenException();
            else return folderFragment.currentDir;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
        {
            switch (arg0.getId())
            {
                case R.id.listNavigation:
                    NavDrawerAdapter.NavDrawerItem item = (NavDrawerAdapter.NavDrawerItem) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
                    if (item.onClicked(this))
                        drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                    break;

                case R.id.listClipboard:
                    FolderFragment folderFragment = getFolderFragment();
                    if (folderFragment != null)
                    {
                        // TODO: paste single file
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public File getLastFolder()
        {
            return lastFolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClipboardContentsChange(Clipboard clipboard)
        {
            invalidateOptionsMenu();

            ListView clipboardListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listClipboard);

            if (clipboard.isEmpty() && drawerLayout != null)
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, Gravity.END);
            else 
            {
                drawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED, Gravity.END);
                FileManagerApplication application = (FileManagerApplication) getApplication();
                if (clipboardListView != null)
                {
                    ClipboardFileAdapter clipboardFileAdapter = new ClipboardFileAdapter(this, clipboard, application.getFileIconResolver());
                    clipboardFileAdapter.setFontApplicator(fontApplicator);
                    clipboardListView.setAdapter(clipboardFileAdapter);
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFavouritesChanged(FavouritesManager favouritesManager)
        {
            loadFavourites(favouritesManager);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
        {
            Log.d("Key Long Press", event.toString());
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
            {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            else return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
        }

    }
```

and the activity where I want to call

```
    package edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.demo;

import static android.widget.Toast.makeText;
import static edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizerSetup.defaultSetup;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.evolution.filemanager.about.AboutActivity;
import com.evolution.filemanager.folders.FolderActivity;
import com.evolution.utils.DataClearer;

import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Assets;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.Hypothesis;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.RecognitionListener;
import edu.cmu.pocketsphinx.SpeechRecognizer;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        RecognitionListener {

    public AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

    private static final String KWS_SEARCH = "wakeup";
    private static final String FORECAST_SEARCH = "forecast";
    private static final String DIGITS_SEARCH = "digits";
    private static final String MENU_SEARCH = "menu";
    private static final String KEYPHRASE = "frost";

    private static final String GO_BACK = "back"; 
    private static final String PREVIOUS = "previous";

    private static final String OPEN_FILE_MANAGER = "open file manager";
    private static final String OPEN_ABOUT = "open about";
    private static final String OPEN_MUSIC = "open music";
    private static final String OPEN_PICTURES = "open pictures";
    private static final String OPEN_VIDEOS = "open videos";
    private static final String SHOW_COMMANDS = "show commands";

    private static final String CLOSE_FILE_MANAGER = "close file manager";
    private static final String CLOSE_ABOUT = "close about";
    private static final String CLOSE_MUSIC = "close music";
    private static final String CLOSE_PICTURES = "close pictures";
    private static final String CLOSE_VIDEOS = "close videos";
    private static final String CLOSE_COMMANDS = "close commands";

    private static final String SHOW_DRAWER = "show drawer";
    private static final String HIDE_DRAWER = "hide drawer";

    public static boolean isOPEN_FILE_MANAGER = false;
    private static boolean isOPEN_ABOUT = false;
    private static boolean isOPEN_MUSIC = false;
    private static boolean isOPEN_PICTURES = false;
    private static boolean isOPEN_VIDEOS = false;
    private static boolean isSHOW_COMMANDS = false;
    private static boolean isSHOW_DRAWER = false;

    private static String MENU_CAPTION;

    private SpeechRecognizer recognizer;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> captions;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle state) {
        super.onCreate(state);

        // Prepare the data for UI
        captions = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        captions.put(KWS_SEARCH, R.string.kws_caption);
        captions.put(MENU_SEARCH, R.string.menu_caption);
        captions.put(DIGITS_SEARCH, R.string.digits_caption);
        captions.put(FORECAST_SEARCH, R.string.forecast_caption);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                .setText("Preparing the recognizer");

        ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewAnim);
        rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.heart_animation);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();

        // Recognizer initialization is a time-consuming and it involves IO,
        // so we execute it in async task

        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
            @Override
            protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
                try {
                    Assets assets = new Assets(PocketSphinxActivity.this);
                    File assetDir = assets.syncAssets();
                    setupRecognizer(assetDir);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return e;
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Exception result) {
                if (result != null) {
                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text))
                            .setText("Failed to init recognizer " + result);
                } else {
                    switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                }
            }
        }.execute();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPartialResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
        TextView tv = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text));

        if (text.equals(KEYPHRASE))
        {
            switchSearch(MENU_SEARCH);
            rocketAnimation.start();
        }
        else if (text.equals(OPEN_FILE_MANAGER))
        {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            Intent intent = new Intent (PocketSphinxActivity.this , FolderActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            isOPEN_FILE_MANAGER = true;

        }
        else if (text.equals(CLOSE_FILE_MANAGER))
        {
            if(isOPEN_FILE_MANAGER == true)
            {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                FolderActivity.FOLDERACTIVITY.finish();
                isOPEN_FILE_MANAGER = false;
            }
        }
        else if (text.equals(SHOW_COMMANDS))
        {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            Intent intent = new Intent (PocketSphinxActivity.this , Commands.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            isSHOW_COMMANDS = true;

        }
        else if (text.equals(CLOSE_COMMANDS))
        {
            if(isSHOW_COMMANDS == true)
            {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                Commands.SHOWCOMMANDS.finish();
            }
        }
        else if (text.equals(OPEN_PICTURES))
        {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            Intent intent = new Intent (PocketSphinxActivity.this , AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else if(text.equals(OPEN_ABOUT))
        {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            Intent intent = new Intent(PocketSphinxActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            isOPEN_ABOUT = true;
        }
        else if(text.equals(CLOSE_ABOUT))
        {
            if (isOPEN_ABOUT == true)
            {
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
                AboutActivity.ABOUTACTIVITY.finish();
            }
        }

        else if(text.equals(GO_BACK) || text.equals(PREVIOUS))
        {
            if(isOPEN_FILE_MANAGER == true )
            {
                FolderActivity.FOLDERACTIVITY//where i want to call onOptionsItemSelected
                switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText(text);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResult(Hypothesis hypothesis) {
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_text)).setText("");
        if (hypothesis != null) {
            String text = hypothesis.getHypstr();
            makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        if (DIGITS_SEARCH.equals(recognizer.getSearchName())
                || FORECAST_SEARCH.equals(recognizer.getSearchName())
                || OPEN_FILE_MANAGER.equals(recognizer.getSearchName()))
            switchSearch(KWS_SEARCH);
    }

    private void switchSearch(String searchName) {
        recognizer.stop();
        recognizer.startListening(searchName);
        String caption = getResources().getString(captions.get(searchName));
        ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.caption_text)).setText(caption);
    }

    private void setupRecognizer(File assetsDir) {
        File modelsDir = new File(assetsDir, "models");
        recognizer = defaultSetup()
                .setAcousticModel(new File(modelsDir, "hmm/en-us-semi"))
                .setDictionary(new File(modelsDir, "dict/cmu07a.dic"))
                .setRawLogDir(assetsDir).setKeywordThreshold(1e-20f)
                .getRecognizer();
        recognizer.addListener(this);

        // Create keyword-activation search.
        recognizer.addKeyphraseSearch(KWS_SEARCH, KEYPHRASE);
        // Create grammar-based searches.
        File menuGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/menu.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(MENU_SEARCH, menuGrammar);
        File digitsGrammar = new File(modelsDir, "grammar/digits.gram");
        recognizer.addGrammarSearch(DIGITS_SEARCH, digitsGrammar);
        // Create language model search.
        File languageModel = new File(modelsDir, "lm/weather.dmp");
        recognizer.addNgramSearch(FORECAST_SEARCH, languageModel);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
    }

    //Fires after the OnStop() state
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
       try {
          trimCache(this); //clear cache to minimize the app size
          DataClearer.getInstance().clearApplicationData();
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO Auto-generated catch block
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }

    public static void trimCache(Context context) {
       try {
          File dir = context.getCacheDir();
          if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
             deleteDir(dir);
          }
       } catch (Exception e) {
          // TODO: handle exception
       }
    }

    public static boolean deleteDir(File dir) {
       if (dir != null && dir.isDirectory()) {
          String[] children = dir.list();
          for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
             boolean success = deleteDir(new File(dir, children[i]));
             if (!success) {
                return false;
             }
          }
       }

       // The directory is now empty so delete it
       return dir.delete();
    }

}
```

the FolderActivity runs on top of the MainActivty but the voice recognition in MainActivity is still active and I want the voice itself do some manipulation in the FolderActivity

Comment: If it's a new activity, why would you want to call the menu from the other activity?

Comment: the FolderActivity runs on top of the MainActivty but the voice recognition in MainActivity is still active and I want the voice itself do some manipulation in the FolderActivity

Comment: Chain it: from the listener call the method on the other Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few suggestions:

1. Have `FolderActivity` register a `BroadcastReceiver` as a listener for a certain `Intent`. When `MainActivity` wants to do something in `FolderActivity`, it can send a broadcast `Intent` which will be seen by the `BroadcastReceiver` in `FolderActivity`, which can then call the appropriate method in the `Activity.
2. When `MainActivity` wants to do something in `FolderActivity`, it can launch `FolderActivity` again using an `Intent` with flag `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` and some "extra" that describes what `FolderActivity` should do. In `FolderActivity` override `onNewIntent()`, read the passed `Intent` parameter and use it to determine what method to call in `FolderActivity. Because the Activity was launched with`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP`, Android won't create a new instance of the Activity, it will just call`onNewIntent()` on the existing instance.
3. Have `FolderActivity` set a `public static` variable of type `Activity` to a reference to itself in `onCreate()`. `MainActivity` can then call a method on `FolderActivity` by doing something like `FolderActivity.activityReference.doSomething()`

Method 3 is not the preferred method, since you need to make sure that you set the `public static` variable to `null` in `FolderActivity.onDestroy()` and there are other concerns (timing issues, memory leaks, etc.) that need to be dealt with properly.

NOTE: You probably don't want to call `onOptionsItemSelected()` directly. This method is called by the Android framework when an options item is selected by the user. You should call directly the method that actually does something, not this framework callback method.